# Jquery get javascript file without running

Tags: jquery

I want to get content of a file using jquery, normally i can use:

`$.get("file", function(data) { alert(data) }`

When i try to get javascript file, jquery run the javascript code before returning callback.

How to get file content without running its code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `dataType` argument to `$.get()` to `"text"` to tell jQuery that the data is a string and it should not guess the type.

```
$.get("file", function(data) { alert(data) }, "text");
```

`$.get()` is just a shortcut for `$.ajax()` and you can see in the [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that the `dataType` argument has a number of values you can pass to the ajax call.  The default is an intelligent guess which probably figures out that it's a script so it executes it.  One of the possibilities is `"text"` which sounds like what you want.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using the load() method of the Jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/load/